# LinkedIn and Open Graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api

I use open graph meta tags in my web. The Google Plus buttons are good and seems that read the tags, but linkedin buttons not.

I don't know if there are other metas for LinkedIn or what.

Answer (score 2):

To the guys using Wordpress and having Better Security Plugin installed, you need to remove the following line in your .htaccess file under the wordpress installation folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [NC,OR]
```

This line is blocking the LinkedIn bots.

Answer (score 1):

Victor, the Linkedin Scraper has significant issues. It looks like it had issues back when you posted this and it still has issues as of right now. There are several threads on their developers forum -- however, some say it's not a developers issues because it doesn't use their API...As long as you have the correct OGP settings (described at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares) I wouldn't worry about it.